# MVVM Light Send Message From a View

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

Is it possible in MVVM Light to send a message from a view to a viewmodel?

MyView.xaml contains a view called MyMapView.xaml.  I want to send a message from MyMapView.xaml to MyOtherViewModel.cs.  MyView.xaml is bound to a different view model than MyOtherViewModel.cs.

Right now the only class that is receiving my message is the one that is sending it (MyMapView.xaml both sends and receives the message) but MyView.xaml and MyOtherViewModel.cs do not receive the message.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyMapView` should have its own `MyMapViewModel`, from which you would send a message using the MVVMLight `Messenger`.

Comment: So it is not possible to send a message from a View?  A ViewModel is required?

Comment: it is possible, but why would you need to do it? The whole point of MVVM is t o abstract the View from the ViewModel. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: MyMapView.xaml is an isolated user control that does not currently have a VM because all of the interaction is Map API specific and very mouse/touch responsive (whereas none of the other Views or ViewModels in my app know about the map).  I am using a 3rd party map tool and did not see a good way to create a ViewModel for this control.  I wanted to send a simple message from the View that transforms a map item into a simple .NET object and send this message to other areas of my app.  I can create a VM to do this, but it seemed unnecessary to send a single message.